# Providing themes as an add-on (additional download, image sets) for an app

Tags: android

I've got an Android app that can be themed using a set of images.  It lets users select which style of images to use, but in order to keep the main app small and let users download/manage only the additional image sets that they would use I want to offer add-on downloads (like extensions).

What's the best way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Handcent, a mms app that I use, had all their themes on the market. What I guess they did is just keep the file structure the same and when the user downloaded the apk data folder, it was placed into the already existing apk tree of the primary Handcent application. I have no idea if that's how they did it, but I can't see why it wouldn't be feasible.

Comment: Right--I use the same messaging app, and I've seen them, so I think it's possible.  I'm just not sure the best way to do it, or really how to at all.  Know of any good resources for doing what you mentioned?  I'm not too familiar with apk trees...

Comment: It's really just a term I token. All an apk is really is a zipped folder of folders, so when you install an application you create a directory tree. So I theorize that if you create another application with the exact same name but different resource folder name, they will just merge when installed. I have no proof that this will work, and if I had more time, I would try it for you. But I would condsider giving it a go.